# form input and place holder not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The subscribe form works but the place holder text isn't visible and when you try to type you cannot see what you're typing either. Works in Chrome and Internet Explorer but not in Firefox.

I've included an image of what it looks like in chrome and in firefox[image]

```css
.nform .input-group .input {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 30px;
}
.nform .form-control {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #6a6a6a;
}
.form .input-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.footer-distributed form {
  display: inline-block;
}
.footer-distributed form input,
.footer-distributed form textarea {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #969696;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 18px;
}
.footer-distributed::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #5c666b;
}
.footer-distributed::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #00aaff;
  opacity: 1;
}
.footer-distributed:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #00aaff;
}
.footer-distributed form input {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.footer-distributed form textarea {
  height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-distributed form button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00bbff;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 6px 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 42px;
}
.footer-distributed form button:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #00bbff;
  border: 1px solid #00bfff;
  padding: 6px 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class=" subscribe-foot section-wrapper">
    <p class="subscribe-nowfoot">
      text
      <br>text
    </p>

    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-2">
      <form class="nform">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control border-radius" placeholder="Email address">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-form border-radius " type="button">Sign up</button>
    </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://www.evernote.com/l/AAN-6DigPgRLY5fqeRPItsWLhaQsG7Z0eNc) the problem.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem either.  Works in Chrome and Firefox.